# What is the difference between AsNoTracking and AutoDetectChangesEnabled false

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I am new to AsNoTracking method. Can you please explain me what is the difference in calling AsNoTracking method and setting AutoDetectChangesEnabled to false?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AsNoTracking does the thing just for the requested resultset.
But AutoDetechChangesEnabled does that for whole dbset.